# Moving Opportunity Team Members from Oppty1 to Oppt2

Tags: apex, opportunity, opportunity-teams

I want to move all the opportunity team members from one opportunity to another. In terms of the query, I'm able to query all of them with this query :

```
List<OpportunityTeamMember> l = [Select Name,TeamMemberRole from OpportunityTeamMember where opportunityId = '1234567'];
```

*The `OpportunityId` in my query is correct. Once I got the members, I attempted to use a for loop to iterate and create a new `TeamMemberRole` object assigning both the `Name and Role` in context of the iteration. But it says, that `Name is not writeable` so I'm wondering if there's another way around this

```
for(OpportunityTeamMember o : l) {
    OpportunityTeamMember otm = new OpportunityTeamMember();
    otm.Name = o.Name; //Issue
    otm.TeamMemberRole = o.TeamMemberRole;
    otm.OpportunityId = 'newId';
}
```

Comment: Gah `DML` in a `for` loop! What is it you think the `Name` field does, exactly?

Comment: lol I know ...I just put it there so everyone knows that I want to insert it. I'll just remove it. Its a lookup field, right? I mean looking through the Salesforce Inspector I see it as a String value

Comment: No, `Name` is not a lookup field...it is indeed a `String`. Are you perhaps looking for `UserId`? Here's the `OpportunityTeamMember` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunityteammember.htm) for reference. I always search for it by googling `<sObjectType> SOAP Salesforce`. Always start by looking at the information, and describe the fields to get more (meta)data if you need it.

Comment: Also, just use the `sObject.clone` method. I should just write up an answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the `OpportunityTeamMember` records and just change the `OpportunityId` if you want to move the team. You may also wish to delete the old records, it is unclear from your post. Something like:

```
List<OpportunityTeamMembers> newTeam = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
for (OpportunityTeamMember member : existingMembers)
{
    OpportunityTeamMember newMember = member.clone();
    newMember.OpportunityId = someOpportunityId;
    newTeam.add(newMember);
}
insert newTeam;
```

Error handling should be included, but that tends to be context dependent and you haven't shared your context.

Comment: Also need to add fields required into the query or clone won't pick them up: `List<OpportunityTeamMember> existingMembers = [SELECT Id, OpportunityAccessLevel, OpportunityId, TeamMemberRole, UserId FROM OpportunityTeamMember WHERE OpportunityId = '1234567'];`

Comment: What exactly does `clone()` duplicate?

Comment: @user The `sObject` you call it on. In this case, the existing `OpportunityTeamMember` record (that you query for in your OP).